# Chrome parses JS file before finishing loading the one above

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have 2 JS files, which are put at the bottom of the page: `vendor.js` which contains minimized libraries, and `master.js`, which contains project JS code. I noticed, however, that sometimes Chrome executes the second file first, before first has finished loading, and this causes the page to not function.
Both files are not declared with `async`:
[image]

Chrome Profiler shows this:

[image]

I may understand why Chrome starts loading the second one, but why execute it, if the one above is not loaded yet? This effect happens almost every time when I enable network throttling.

Comment: Not an answer, but it's better to use `defer` attribute and add scripts to the head

Comment: is there anything in "the first js" that is asynchronous? coz, chrome won't wait for dat

Answer (score 0):

If some content of `vendor.js` is `asynchronous` it will be executed later and will not prevent starting the `master.js` from executing.

Comment: How can you check for that?